# What is cloud computing?

Tags: terminology, cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Cloud computing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108037/what-is-cloud-computing)

I read the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) article on it and am still confused.  I know there is a great deal of hype these days surrounding 'Cloud Computing', but what is it exactly?

**From a programmer's prespective**:

1. If I am creating a web service that process all my business rules and data storage on a web server, is that cloud computing?
2. Are all websites examples of cloud computing?
3. Just becuase I use WCF or Web Services does that automatically make it a cloud application?