# Cloud Apps vs Web Apps

Tags: php, ajax, cloud

I have 2 questions: 
First, what's the difference between a web application and a cloud application? Are there any differences at all? If I'm developing a web application (a site with many interactive features), can I call it a cloud application? 
Second, if there's a difference between a cloud and web application, what languages can cloud applications be developed in? Would a scripting language like PHP be useful for that? 

 
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I have watched the video in one of the answers, but I am still a little confused. Taking Google Docs as a example, all I see is a user interface that can be created with html and JS, along with a server script, and the data is stored in a database, which is basically the same thing a web application does. Or is it different? 
Thanks

Comment: "cloud app" sounds like sales talk, but could mean an app that can be deployed and scaled as fast as cloud servers.

Comment: @user:A "cloud" is composed of web applications.The technologies are the same.You are missing the context

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web applications can run on "the cloud". The cloud is basically a collection of dynamic computational resources (cpu, ram, storage etc) that can be used by web applications.

This allows apps running on the cloud to scale well because they are allocated resources dynamically.

You can use public clouds such as Amazon's EC2 - or build your own private clouds.

A web app running on a cloud isn't exactly a "cloud app" - but the app is simply hosted on a cloud.

I find the first half of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ST_t3bgYPDk) explains it very well (if a little annoying).

Also see [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108037/840973) which has some good answers.

Answer (score 1):

A web application is an just an application deployed on a web server.
The user accesses this application knowing that it is accessing a remote application and this application has a specific purpose.I.e. implements a specific functionality.

When you start talking about the cloud, you have a different concept alltogether.
The idea is that you want to access a `service` that you have no idea where the service actually is being deployed.
The main benefit is that a company can save resources.
For example a company can have e.g. their own CRM and have to pay money for servers, for IT personel etc. or just access a service in a "cloud" where the company providing the cloud is responsible for the servers etc.

So to answer your question, to build the cloud you use web applications as "modules" to provide the cloud.

But a web application by itself (separate of this context) can not be considered as cloud application (unless it runs as part of the cloud).

Answer (score 0):

Anything that runs locally can run in a "cloud".  Cloud computing is the inevitable movement of traditional applications/processes to a dedicated provider.  Analogous to the Walmart syndrome, where little mom and pop shops have fallen by the wayside.

The difference between a cloud and web application is where it sits.

Comment: How's that a difference? They both sit on the web server, right?

Answer (score 0):

Web and cloud apps both are distributed applications having server and client parts. They store data on a server side, but can have local data cache for offline cases.

Web applications performed/run ***by browsers***. Normally, they are written on HTMP/CSS/JavaScript. Adobe had another vision of client parts. They proposed special Flex language for Abobe Flash as client run-time environment (prior it has been killed this year).

Cloud apps are very similar to web apps, but their client parts are native applications specially developed to run on selected target platforms (OS X, Win, iOS, etc.)